# For what parameter $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ is this function integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

**Problem:** For what values of the parameter $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ is the function $$ f: (0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}: x \mapsto \frac{x-1}{x^{\alpha} \ln(x)} $$ integrable?

**My attempt:** Notice that $$\lim_{x \to 1} f(x) x^{\alpha} = \lim_{x \to 1} \frac{x-1}{\ln(x)} = 1 $$ by the use of l'Hopital. This means that $f(x) = \Theta(\frac{1}{x^{\alpha}})$ for $x \to 1$, i.e. $f(x)$ is asymptotically bounded by this function. So for $x \to 1$, we know that we must have $\alpha > 1$ for $f$ to be integrable.

Now I wanted to determine the behavior of this function near $x = 0$. I let $\alpha = 1$ first. Let $\epsilon > 0$ and consider the interval $(\epsilon, 1/e)$. Is $f$ integrable on this interval?

We have $$ \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{\epsilon}^{1/e} f(x) dx = - \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{\epsilon}^{1/e} \frac{1-x}{x\ln(x)} dx \leq - \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{\epsilon}^{1/e} \frac{1}{x \ln(x)} dx. $$ Now if I let $u = \ln(x)$, then the limits of integration change to $\ln(\epsilon)$ and $-1$, but I would get $$ - \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \big[ \ln(u) \big]_{\ln(\epsilon)}^{-1} $$ which is not defined.

I'm not sure how to determine the whether this function is integrable around zero, and for what value of the parameter. Any help/suggestions is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We assume $ x \in (0,1)$. There is no problem near the bound $1^-$.

- Assume $0<\alpha<1$. For $0<x<1/e$, we have $$
     0<-\frac{1}{x^\alpha\ln x}\le \frac1{x^{\alpha}} $$ and$$
     0<\frac{x-1}{x^\alpha\ln x}\le \frac{1-x}{x^{\alpha}} $$ giving $$
     0<\int_0^{1/e}\frac{x-1}{x^\alpha\ln x}\:dx\le
     \int_0^{1/e}\frac{1-x}{x^{\alpha}}\:dx=\left[x^{1-\alpha}
     \left(\frac{1}{1-\alpha}-\frac{x}{2-\alpha}\right)\right]_0^{1/e}<\infty
     $$ and *the given integral is convergent*.
- Assume $\alpha=1$. Then $$ \int_0^{1/e}\frac{-1}{x^\alpha\ln
     x}\:dx=\lim_{t \to 0^+} \left[-\ln(-\ln
     x)\frac{}{}\right]_t^{1/e}=\infty $$ and *the given integral is
  divergent*.
- Assume $\alpha>1$. By the change of variable $u=-\ln x$, we have $$
     \int_0^{1/e}\frac{-1}{x^\alpha\ln
     x}\:dx=\int_1^{\infty}\frac{e^{(\alpha-1)u}}{u}\:du=\infty $$ and
  *the given integral is divergent*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I don't quite understand how you change the limits of integration in the last case, where $\alpha > 1$. If you set $u = -\ln(x)$, then the limits of integration should be $- \ln(0)$ which is not defined, and $-\ln(1/e) = 1$?

Comment: You are welcome. With $u=-\ln x$, as $x \to 0^+$ then $u \to +\infty$, giving $\int_{0^+}^{1/e} -1/(x^\alpha \ln x)dx=-\int_{+\infty}^{1}\frac{e^{-u}}{e^{-\alpha u}u}\:du=\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{e^{(\alpha-1)u}}{u}\:du$ which diverges for $\alpha >1$.

Comment: I see. One final question: how do you know that $- \frac{1}{x^{\alpha} \ln(x)} \leq \frac{1}{x^{\alpha}} $ for the first case? How do you see that?

Comment: If $0<x\le 1/e$, then $\ln x \le \ln (1/e)$ ($\ln (\cdot)$ is an increasing function), then $\ln x \le -1$, then $-\ln x \ge 1$, then $\frac1{-\ln x} \le 1$ and $- \frac{1}{x^{\alpha} \ln(x)} \leq \frac{1}{x^{\alpha}}$ (since $x^\alpha>0$).

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$f(x)=\frac{x-1}{x^\alpha\ln(x)}$$ for

$0<x<1$ and $\alpha\in\mathbb R$.

we have

> at $ x=1,$  it converges since

$\lim_{x\to 1^-}f(x)=1$.

> at$\;\;x=0$

- $\alpha>1$

Let $\alpha>a>1$

$lim_{x\to 0^+}x^af(x)=\infty \implies \int_0f(x)dx$ diverges.

- $\alpha<1$

let $\alpha<b<1$

$\lim_{x\to 0^+}x^bf(x)=0 \implies \int_0 f(x)dx$ converges.

- $\alpha=1$

$F(x)=\int_x f(t)dt=-(\ln(|\ln(x)|))$ 
goes to $\infty$.